# Swig: ValueWrapper and Templates BUG?

Tags: c++, swig

I tried to get a SmartPointer-Template-Type not surrounded by a ValueWrapper for an in typemap. I didn't find a solution. So I checked the swig source code and realized that `SwigType_alttype` in `typsys.c` is setting `use_wrapper` to true for all templates. `use_wrapper = !n || !GetFlag(n, "feature:novaluewrapper");` is always `true`, because of `!n`. Is this on purpose or a bug?

```
n = Swig_symbol_clookup(td, 0);
      if (n) {
    if (GetFlag(n, "feature:valuewrapper")) {
      use_wrapper = 1;
    } else {
      if (Checkattr(n, "nodeType", "class")
          && (!Getattr(n, "allocate:default_constructor")
          || (Getattr(n, "allocate:noassign")))) {
        use_wrapper = !GetFlag(n, "feature:novaluewrapper") || GetFlag(n, "feature:nodefault");
      }
    }
      } else {
    if (SwigType_issimple(td) && SwigType_istemplate(td)) {
      use_wrapper = !n || !GetFlag(n, "feature:novaluewrapper");
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why they did this but I found a work around from https://web.archive.org/web/20171227205037/http://swig-user.narkive.com/f3gshV1S/swigvaluewrapper-being-used-for-unknown-templates.

From the last post:

> I've found a neat solution to solve this using the %template directive 
>   without a name,
>
> %template() std::auto_ptr;

I've used it myself and while annoying that you have to declare for every type it's not too bad.